# Angular pipe with multiple patterns

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, formatting

I have a simple custom pipe that implements DecimalPipe transform() method, like so:

```
export class MyDecimalFormatPipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(public decimalPipe: DecimalPipe) {};

    transform(value: any) {
        if (value || value === 0) {
            value = this.decimalPipe.transform(value, '1.2-2');
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

This is the plunker link: https://plnkr.co/edit/eEfXoXdM1OakuX1TjR1N?p=preview
Obviously , this is not much of a custom pipe, as it implements DecimalPipe, but my ultimate goal is to have this pipe support more patterns other than '1.2-2'.  I did some research and everyone seems to using control structures like if/else or switch statements.  I suppose that would look like:

```
export class MyDecimalFormatPipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(public decimalPipe: DecimalPipe) {};

    transform(value: any) {
        if (somevalue) {
            let format = '1.2-2'
            value = this.decimalPipe.transform(value, format);
        }
        else if (othervalue) {
            let format = '1.4-4'
            value = this.decimalPipe.transform(value, format);
        }
        ...
        return value
    }
}
```

This seems wrong and 'clunky' and this method would get rather large as we add more format patterns.  I suppose a pipe should have a number of pre-set format patterns that will be set based on the input value.  One could create a method for this perhaps, like so:

```
setFormatPattern(inputPattern: string): string {
    let pattern: any;
    this.myPatternsArray.forEach(element => {
        if (element.format === inputPattern ) {
           pattern = element.pattern;
        }
    });
    return pattern;
}
```

I am struggling with design as well as the implementation(code) of this problem.  There must be an easier way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a parameter to your pipe like this:

```
{{ whatever | mypipe: 'option1' }}
```

This will be passed into your pipe.ts as args:

```
transform(value: any, args?: string) {
  switch (args) {
    case 'option1':
      return handleOption1(value);
    case 'option2':
      return handleOption2(value);
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: well in such a case I would just use DecimalPipe format like so: {{ whatever | myDecimalPipe: '1.4-4' }} and so on.  I am looking for a solution where the pipe itself stores a number of format patterns.

Comment: And how would you like to define the format when using your pipe?

Comment: What about having something like `private myPatterns = [ {patternA: '1.4-4'}, {patternB: '1.2-2}, {patternC: '1.9-9} ]`

Comment: Ok, and when I use your pipe like "{{ myvar | myDecimalPipe }}", which pattern should be used?

Comment: @MadCatm2 - what's the advantage for you to declare another pipe just to map the string '1.4-4' with 'patternA'?

Comment: Lets say your example:  
`transform(value: any, args?: string) {
  switch (args) {
    case '1.2-2':
      value = this.decimalPipe.transform(value)
    case '1.4-4':
      value = this.decimalPipe.transform(value)
    case '1.9-9'
  }
}`
Is this the best way really the best way...I am really curious...

Answer (score 0):

You can use extra parameter by which you pas the format to your pipe, maybe you want something like this:

```
export class MyDecimalFormatPipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(public decimalPipe: DecimalPipe) {};

    transform(value: any, format: string) {
        return this.decimalPipe.transform(value, format);
    }
} 

// You then use your pipe like ...:

{{ something | myDecimalPipe: '1.4-4'}}
```